# there are no categorized items eclipse - Genymotion

Tags: eclipse, genymotion

Please help me :

there are no categorized items eclipse - Genymotion

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What happens when you do as it says in the `Details` field?

Answer (score 29):

Uncheck `Group items by category`

Comment: Bartosz, you made my day...I have been looking for the fix, thanks a lot.